# on click blur using javascript+css (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, webkit, blur

I currently have the following function in template.someName.events. What it does is it basically blurs the current page and loads a overlay page.

Everything works fine except that its very laggy... Very very laggy... Would there be any way to improve this for it to be smooth?

```
Template.someName.events({

'click .someButtonCluss': function(){

//.../// Code for calling overlay screen

  blurElement

(".wrapper", 0.3);

      function blurElement(element, size){
        var filterVal = 'blur('+size+'px)';
        $(element)
          .css('filter',filterVal)
          .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
          .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
          .css('oFilter',filterVal)
          .css('msFilter',filterVal);


     }
}
}):
```

Comment: @vaultah I tried that and it didn't seem to help at all...

Comment: Please refrain from asking questions that amount to "can you fix this for me?"

Comment: @JoshBurgees I do not want a full coded fix for myself. I'm just wondering why this simple function is so laggy, and would like pointers.

Comment: What if you flip the order of your "code for calling overlay screen" and blurElement() ?

Comment: @colllin Thanks. I did try it just now, however its still pretty laggy. I guess I'll have to find some other way. It's not a major part that I need so I'll work on it some other time and post updates in the edit in the future. In the meanwhile, if anyone has ideas or pointers, it would be greatly appreciated.